# See ALS persistent volume data in Storage explorer

Tags: azure, kubernetes

anyone know how i can see my aks persisted volume (azurefile) data in Azure Storage Explorer or in the portal?

persisted volume is working but i can't see the raw files somehow..

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azurefile
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
parameters:
  storageAccount: trstorage


apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  hostPath:
    path: "/data/mysql"
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: azurefile
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: azurefile
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500Mi
```

p.s. i know it's a bad idea to use azurefile for a database so ignore that for now.

when i look in the storage account i don't see any files, that's what i'm not understanding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, I understand that you did the persisted volume in Azure Storage for your mysql in Azure Kubenets.

First, if your mount path is right and the path that mysql will automatically create files itself. You will see files in Azure Storage Explorer or in the portal with File Share.

Second, you can check if Azure Storage File Share was mounted correctly to the mount point. You can use the command `kubectl describe pod podName` to check it. The resulting screenshot will like this.
[image]

Or check it in the browser with the command `az aks browse --resource-group resourceGroupName --name AKSClusterName`. And the resulting screenshot will like this.
[image]

Third, you can check the path with connecting to the AKS node. For connecting, you can follow the document [SSH into Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/aks-ssh).

I did the test and the resulting screenshots here:

See persisted Volume in the portal. 
[image]

See persisted Volume in the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Charles, I'm going to give this a go again, it didn't appear to work the first time around so i move to static as opposed to dynamic, and then i could see files in AzureStorageExplorer, but i like the dynamic approach and now that i've had a little more experience i'll give it another shot and let you know how i get on.

Comment: That's ok, we can talk more about persisted volume in the other case. And if the answer is helpful you can accept it, thx.

Comment: ok tried it again and it does indeed work, if i was to guess at what i did wrong, i'd say i perhaps added an invalid storage account name. Also the AKS docs dont show where to specify the storageaccount name, the yaml provided doesn't  have the parameters section, docs do however reference that it should be updates/set.. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azurefile
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000  
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS  
  storageAccount: gdkstore
```

note: 
storageAccount:  is what's missing from MS docs currently
change gdkstore to your own storage account name in the correct resource group